# How to convert my Node js app to a single page angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

js app that I use MEAN stack at that time I didn't know there was such of thing like mean stack. The problem im having is that I use a more common web approach for example I don't handle my routing in angular I use the traditional full page reload using node/express.js.

I have two question for the experience MEAN stack developer first does it worth it to change my routing to use angular so I can have a more traditional MEAN stack app and the second question is what would be a good file structure to my already builded application for example do i make my "/" route to send `res.sendfile('./public/index.html');`and then I can control the routing for my angular?

I'm just looking for any advice before I make the change. I don't think it would take me that long since I already use all the technologies.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, and I would encourage you to make the switch. First, like you said, it wouldn't take a lot of time to do. Therefore the cost of learning a new approach is minimal and  you stand to lose nothing by it. I think you'll be happy with the results. Serve up a single page on / like you suggested, handle routing in angular instead of in the server, and keep your views in your /app folder, or whatever you like to use. The rest of your servers routes can serve as an API for AJAX requests for data.